# Javascript call-stack

Tags: javascript, callstack

I have a problem in which the call-stack is fill with a lot of functions, recursions, timeouts, animation delays and so on. The thing I want to do is to keep a track of the js call-stack and when it is empty or at least it is 95% finished so I can invoke another last function which has to do some stuff. I tried to invoke that function when all my promises are resolved, even at the very very last thing I thought it would work, but unfortunatelly it still doesn't or maybe I am doing it wrong. So the question is how can I keep a track of the queue and when it is emptied to do some stuff.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://example.com)

Comment: @DannyMoshe FYI, you can just type `[mre]` and it will fill in [mre] :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Thank you kindly sir!

Comment: If you are getting to the point where you have to track the call stack manually (maybe you're getting `Maximum call stack exceeded`?), you're likely doing something wrong, and you should consider fixing that instead of looking at self-managing the call stack. Note that writing code to track the call stack manually would involve you calling an extra piece of tracking code at the start and end of every piece of code you write, or at least writing interception code that did it for you. I believe that an answer that mapped that out for you would be far too long for a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: The call-stack is too "under the hood" for js. Your js code uses and affects the call-stack not the other way around.

Comment: I don't get any call-stacks exceeded. I am doing some hard DOM manipulations and work mainly with promises, and all of my stuff is working, but there is 1 out of 100 cases in which I see the browser is a bit laggying, which is kindly breaking some of my stuff, the case is extremelly rare but I beleive its happening due to the code execution. Thats why a possible solution would be to track when the call-stack empties and then to invoke my last function. I manually debugged my code and everything, all values checks etc are working fine, but somehow it doesn't invoke it in right time.

Comment: I don't think there's anything like this available. When the call stack is completely empty it will process the next item in the event queue, so you can use `setInterval(<function>, 0);` to run a function when the call stack clears. But there's nothing that triggers when it's 95% finished (95% of what?).

Comment: @Barmar it was somekind of example. You have a good point about the queue and it may solve my problem, if anyhow I can push my function last in the queue.

Comment: I suggest profiling your code to find the hotspots. Google Chrome has a great profiler built into its developer tools. Generally, measure first, then decide how to fix what you’ve measured...

Comment: Thanks all for the quick and detailed replies. I found a solution via continuous recursion which is checking if the code and the result I want to aplly otherwise it will invoke itself 1 2 more times, not the most optimal solution but fair enough to hotfix.